# Laravel Custom User Roles & Permissions based on routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I've created a custom roles manager for Laravel (4.2) based on the named routes e.g.:

```
users.index, customers.create, vendors.update, orders.store, users.edit, customers.update, etc.
```

Basically anything registered as a `Route::resource(...);` within the routes.php file (with a few custom named routes)

I'm checking the permissions with this method:

```
namespace Acme\Users;

...

class User extends \Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    ...

    public function hasPermissions($route)
    {
        $actions = ['users.index', 'users.create', 'users.edit', 'users.delete']; // fake data
        if ( ! in_array($route, $actions))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then, within the `app/filters.php`, I'm checking the current route against the User.

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest())
    {
        if (Request::ajax())
        {
            return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::guest('login');
        }
    }

    // check if the current authenticated User has permissions to access this route
    if ( ! Auth::user()->hasPermissions(Route::current()->getName())) 
    {   
        return Redirect::route('dashboard.index');
    }
});
```

Everything is working with any route using the GET method, but when it comes to PUT, PATCH, POST DELETE the `Route::current()->getName()` doesn't return anything.

Is there a better approach? I want everything to happen automatically, and I have a solution to this issue, but it's very involved. Is there a way to get the route name during a PUT, PATCH, POST or DELETE request?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add one or two of your routes as example?

Comment: As @lukasgeiter said we need the PUT, PATCH and so on routes.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your verification code inside after filter.

```
App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    if ( ! Auth::user()->hasPermissions(Route::current()->getName())) 
    {   
        return Redirect::route('dashboard.index');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Fabiano, I'll try give this a try later today.